# Настройка андроид студии

Tags: android, android-studio

недавно начал работать с андроид студией, попытался подключить гит и все сломал, все проекты загружаются не так как раньше и ничего не работает, помогите пожалуйста.

Тперь все выглядит вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ранее было вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовал скинуть настройки студии до заводских, не помогло.

Comment: а что по вашему мнению сломалось? не очень понятен вопрос если честно, опишите более подробно что именно вы делали, как было до и после ваших действий

Comment: Поменялось расположение файлов, родительским стал какой-то src в котором все хранится, далее проект просто перестал собираться, а что делал не помню, кликал как на видео из ютубов.

Comment: ну так вообще сложно помочь) если перестал собираться значит есть причина, у вас должно быть сообщение об ошибке, приложите его в вопрос пожалуйста

Comment: Получилось починит, везде удалился build.gradle, слава богу делал резервные копии проектов...